# Multiple QWebEngineProcesses created by QWebEngineView eats up memory

Tags: python, pyside6, qtwebengine, qtwebview

In my application I have a list of buttons and clicking on each creates a new QWebEngineView in a QMainWindow. On closing the QMainWindow I want the QWebEngineView (and the QWebEngineProcess that it spawns) to be destroyed. But this does not happen - if I click on multiple buttons, multiple QWebEngineProcesses are created that eats up memory. Why are these processes not getting killed  even after destroying the web view? Can anyone please help me with this?

[image]

Here is a sample code that I tried while trying to solve this problem. I have a single button here and clicking on it each time creates a new main window with a QWebEngineView.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMainWindow)
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class PlotWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor."""
        super(PlotWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.webV = QWebEngineView()
        self.webV.load('https://en.wikipedia.org/')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webV)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.webV.destroy() # => This does not kill background process QWebEngineProcess



class webView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(webView, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QPushButton('Click')
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.create_plot(self))
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def create_plot(self, widget):
        win = PlotWindow(widget)
        win.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()

    web = webView()
    web.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I came across this : https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/overviews/qtwebengine-features.html#process-models and "Process Per Site" *might* be a possible solution for this problem, but I really do not understand how and where to use the command line arguments. Just passing them as args to QApplication() doesn't work.

Comment: First of all, use `deleteLater()`, not `destroy()`, then you should delete the whole window, not just the view. That should theoretically take care of any remaining reference. If that's not enough, try to delete the page as well, but that should theoretically not happen (unless you're keeping references somewhere else)

Comment: deleteLater() works! it removes the QtWebEngineProcess. Thank you @musicmante

Comment: Note that you can avoid all that (including overriding `closeEvent()`) just by setting the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on the window. See [`QWidget.setAttribute()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute).

Comment: The attribute does not work for some reason for me. I added self.setAtrribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True) in class PlotWindow that inherits QMainWindow

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: I removed the closeEvent override and added the setAttribute as mentioned above. But that did not remove the QtWebEngineProcess on closing the window.